# How to implement impersonation in IdentityServer4

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I would like to know if it is possible to implement impersonation in IdentityServer 4, and how to do it. 
Did not find anything useful in my researches, and it seems, by reading IdentityServer4 pulls on github that it is not doable at the moment. Even searched for "impersonation" for OpenID Connect and Oauth2, but nothing...
Anyway does anyone knows how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is how i implemented it https://www.daimto.com/identity-server-4-user-delegation/

Comment: @DaImTo's approach will work. You'd just need to make sure that in this line `var subject = context.Request.Raw.Get(ServiceAccountRequiredProperty.Subject);` you are passing the `sub` claim of (i.e. the ID) of the user you're trying to impersonate. You can read a bit more about it here: https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/tokens/extension_grants/token_exchange/. This wont help with having two active sessions though. For that I suggest you just use two different browsers, incognito etc.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing stopping you from implementing it yourself but I think anything beyond representing an impersonated session via claims is outside the scope of the protocol.

OIDC itself does not offer any guidance in this area but this draft spec does:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-token-exchange-14#section-4.1

In our case we loosely followed this and used the `act` claim to store claims relating to the impersonator and used the `amr` claim to indicate if impersonation was used by using the value `imp`.

The rules and flow around who can impersonate who and when is entirely up to you. In our solution end users are able to grant impersonation permissions to specific users but this facility can be locked down via customer-controlled policies too. Users with valid impersonation grants get an extra step in the sign in flow that allows them to choose which user to impersonate.

Comment: Many thanks. I will read the documentation you provided, and will try to find some workaround.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you implement updating a user's tokens/sessions in remote sites if they're already authenticated as themselves? e.g.  if a user is already authenticated _as themselves_ with both the IdP and the RP and they now want to impersonate another user, how does the IdP "push" the updated `access_token` to a Front-Channel client - as well as all other front-channel clients the user is currently using?

Comment: @Dai I actually trigger the front & back channel logout mechanism when switching impersonations so any downstream clients are automatically signed out. The session ID is also updated which means any clients using sesion monitoring will get a change notification also.